# How to get department and manager's email through google admin sdk?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-admin-sdk

I am calling google admin directory api to get user through email and then storing the organizations return in org.

```
var user = AdminDirectory.Users.get(bmail);

org = user.organizations;
```

Output

```
[ { customType: '',
    title: 'PM',
    department: 'BIT',
    primary: true,
    description: 'Permanent' } ]
```

- **How can i get only department in org?** I've tried to use get.child(element) to get the department however not successful.
- **How can i get only manager's email?** I've read the [Rest Resource Users](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users#User) but there is no information related to manager's email.

Any reference or help will be much appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have the `User` object, so if you want to read the `department` property you only have to navigate its tree. See the example below:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var user = AdminDirectory.Users.get(bmail);
  org = user['organizations'][0]['department'];
}
```

Now to answer your second question you could use the [`relations`](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users#resource:-user) field to keep track of the user's managers. Feel free to drop a comment if you need further clarifications.